# .NET Remoting keeps a listening socket if I stop debugging server program

Tags: remoting

I have sporadic issue, it is not happening always.

I have windows service which listening on some port (.NET Remoting).
Here the code of registering channel:

```
void RegisterChannel(int portNumber, string bindTo)
{
    ListDictionary channelProperties = new ListDictionary();
    channelProperties.Add("name", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper());
    channelProperties.Add("port", portNumber);
    channelProperties.Add("bindTo", bindTo);
    channelProperties.Add("secure", true.ToString());
    channelProperties.Add("impersonate", true.ToString());
    channelProperties.Add("useIpAddress", false.ToString());

    BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider clientFormatter = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
    BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverFormatter = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
    serverFormatter.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
    TcpChannel tcpChannel = new TcpChannel(channelProperties, clientFormatter, serverFormatter);

    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, true);
}

RegisterChannel(9000, "[::]");
RegisterChannel(9000, "0.0.0.0");
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(AccessServer), "AccessLayer", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

If I start debugging of this service in Visual Studio and then stop debugging, after that I am unable to start debugging.

I am getting following exception:
*Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted*

Running  netstat –anbo shows:

TCP    0.0.0.0:9000   0.0.0.0:0        LISTENING       3432 [System]

TCP    [::]:9000      [::]:0           LISTENING       3432 [System]

After that I have to reboot, otherwise port is taken forever.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is the service process definitely being terminated when you stop debugging? It is possible to start the debugger and then for the process to continue after you detach again - meaning that the service code would still be running and so still be occupying the port.

You also might want to change your service so that you explicitly unregister the channel. I've written Windows Services in the past that use Remoting and in "OnStart" a TcpChannel is configured, just as with the code in your question, then in "OnStop" that channel is unregistered by calling "UnregisterChannel" -

```
public static void UnregisterChannel(IChannel chan)
{
    // Due to some weird behaviour we can only remove the registered channel
    // by spinning through the list of channels
    foreach (IChannel ch in ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels)
    {
        if (ch.Equals(chan))
        {
            ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(ch);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to do this, you'll need to keep a reference to "tcpChannel" hanging around so that you can unregister it when you're finished.

You would think that you could just call "ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel" directly with the tcpChannel reference that you are now keeping hold of until "tidy up time" but I encountered some problems with this - I can't recall precisely what the symptoms were but I remember that they were avoided by looping through the RegisteredChannels set and looking for a reference that claimed to Equals my channel reference and then passing *that* to "ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel".